# CodeIgniter - big site best practices

Tags: codeigniter

CodeIgniter + Template howto design a portal like behavior.

I'm not getting the concept of how to design bigger sites with CodeIgniter and Templates.
The templates I'm using is [Template Library for CodeIgniter](http://williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/index.html). I'm having problems solving the following.

What I can see I need is some MasterTemplate that provides "MainRegion" for ProductCatalogue browsing and Account management etc. Then I would like to have a concept of "Widgets" loaded from the MasterTemplate that the user does not interact directly with instead it is simply informative. Ex: ShoppingCartWidget, TopNews etc...

Example of problems:
A) Widget - A shopping cart widget exposes a minimalistic resume of what user has added when browsing the the product catalog in the "MainRegion". 
B) Hierachival view structure - When navigating to the "Account section" of the site the site renders a sub-view of the account system in the "MainRegion". My problem is that the state of the AccountSection is lost when I for example leave the "AccountSection" in to "ProductCatalogue" and the back to "Accountsection". I want to be able to render each subsection independtly smothly insterted into the "MainRegion" in the master template.

I really don't get the architecture. I need help to bring real modularity into the design.

I would like to achive the following:

1) View fragments should render from a its own model. Ex: ShoppingCartWidget always reads its state from ShoppingCartModel. 
3) View fragments should have a display[on/off] in some MasterTemplate concept. So that I can Ex: Start showing the ShoppingCartWidget when there is something in the ShoppingCart. (I don't want to render '').
4) Stateful views. Ex: UserLoggedIn/UserNotLoggedIn

I'm missing the complex design principles for bigger sites or best practices for CI.

Very greatful for any help!

Thanks

Niclas

Answer (score 1):

HMVC for Codeigniter does what you want: https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/wiki/Home

Comment: OK. I have looked into it and it pretty much is what I'm locking for. One thing that I can't figure out is how to best use it with a TemplateEngine. The top view includes other views - OK. But what if I send a request to  a subcontroller. What triggers the rendering of the main page?

Comment: I wouldn't use the template engine at all. I stick all my code in partials. Loginboxes, headers, footers, sidebars, etc.

Comment: OK. Interesting. Let me know how... What is the overall design? Do you have some main view that are calling the other controllers to include content? I don't get it.

Comment: Generally I several main controllers/views that dont live in in the modules folder. They mostly just call partials. Also you can do quite a bit with routes.

Comment: OK. Let me confirm. You have a main controller that includes sub controllers' partials. That's fine. But when a request is targeted directly to a sub-controller. Do you separate that request as write request (does not render any output) and then let the main-controller only rendering by reading?

Comment: I use the _remap() function and trigger a 404 to prevent unwanted direct access to some of the partials.